# Postgres: The best way to optmize "greater than" query

Tags: postgresql

what is the best way to optimize join query that join with the same table on the next id value at the sub group? For now I have something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_next_id(bigint, bigint) RETURNS bigint AS $body$
DECLARE
    _id bigint;
BEGIN
    SELECT id INTO _id FROM table WHERE id_group = $2 AND id > $1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
    RETURN _id;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the JOIN query:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 ON t2.id = select_next_id(t1.id, t1.id_group)
```

The table have more than 2kk rows, and it takes very very long. Is there a better way to do this quick? Also I have UNIQUE INDEX on column id. Not very helpfull I guess.

Some sample data:

```
id | id_group
=============
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 2
5  | 2
6  | 2
20 | 4
25 | 4
37 | 4
40 | 1
55 | 2
```

And I want to recieve something like this:

```
id | id_next
1  | 2
2  | 3
3  | null
4  | 5 
5  | 6
6  | 55
```

and so on.

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: The "next id" can also be retrieved using the `lead()` function without a self join. Please post some sample data and the expected output to explain what you want.

Comment: Why does `id_next` for `id=3` have the value `null` in your sample output? Shouldn't that be `40` (which is the next higher ID from the same group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the query in the function, you need an index on `(id_group, id)`, not just `(id)`.

Next, you don't need the overhead of plpgsql in the function itself, and you can give a few hints to the planner by making it as stable and having a small cost:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_next_id(bigint, bigint) RETURNS bigint AS $body$
    SELECT id FROM table WHERE id_group = $2 AND id > $1 ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
$body$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE COST 10;
```

In the final query, depending on what you're actually trying to do, you might be able to get rid of the join and the function call by using `lead()` as highlighted by the horse:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think you want something like this:

```
select id, 
       lead(id) over (partition by id_group order by id) as id_next
from the_table
order by id, id_next;
```

Comment: I thought so, but leading and my function returns different values. Query: 
SELECT id, 
 select_next_id(id, id_group), 
 lead(id) OVER (PARTITION BY id_group ORDER BY id ASC)
   FROM table;

And I have following result (not like I should get):
id;next;lead (col names):
178944;187091;187091 <-- OK
187091;207696;382609 <-- NOT OK

Comment: @b4rt3kk please don't post sample data in comments. Create a http://sqlfiddle.com that shows what you want and what the problem is.